# window resize make visual carousel bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use slick.js for a project. Slider works perfect but I have a little visual bug when I resize the window with mouse, I see `next` slider for few seconds. The `active` image need some seconds to get `width: 100%`.

For few seconds the second slider is visibile. How can I fix this? If I drag the window very fast I can see all sliders. [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmcvo.jpg).

Here is a live [exemple](http://codepen.io/wideart/pen/LVjwMg). Make window smaller and after resize with mouse the window.

Comment: Seems to be some kind of browser lag. I see you're concern but what user would resize the browser window like that? ;p

Comment: I don't know. I like to do all things good :d